# Printing a table with php and html: all the results are in the same column

Tags: php, html, css, csv

beginner here! I'm would like to print a table using PHP and HTML, but I'm getting all the results in the same column and I'm unable to identify the error. Could you please give me any suggestions? The full code is above. I'm also using CSS to do it "prettier". Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">

    <title>:: Coefficient de corrélation ::</title>
</head>
<body>


<?php

set_time_limit(0);


$handle = fopen("dados.csv", "r");


//------------------------------------Variable

    $_colonne_matrice_1 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_2 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_3 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_4 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_5 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_6 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_7 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_8 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_9 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_10 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_11 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_12 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_13 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_14 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_15 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_16 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_17 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_18 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_19 = array();
    $_colonne_matrice_20 = array();


    $_colonne_1 = 0;
    $_colonne_2 = 0;
    $_colonne_3 = 0;
    $_colonne_4 = 0;
    $_colonne_5 = 0;
    $_colonne_6 = 0;
    $_colonne_7 = 0;
    $_colonne_8 = 0;
    $_colonne_9 = 0;
    $_colonne_10 = 0;
    $_colonne_11 = 0;
    $_colonne_12 = 0;
    $_colonne_13 = 0;
    $_colonne_14 = 0;
    $_colonne_15 = 0;
    $_colonne_16 = 0;
    $_colonne_17 = 0;
    $_colonne_18 = 0;
    $_colonne_19 = 0;
    $_colonne_20 = 0;



    $sommeT = 0;
    $sommeQ = 0;
    $sommeQQ = 0;
    $sommeQ2 = 0;
    $d = 0;
    $m = array();
    $m0 = array();
    $m1 = array();
    $m2 = array();

    $row = 0;

//-------------------------------Fin des variables

//-------------------------------Manipulation du csv

while ($cols = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";"))
{

    if ($row++ < 1)
    {
        continue;
    }

//--------------------------------somme de chaque colonne

        $_colonne_1 += $cols[1];
        $_colonne_2 += $cols[2];
        $_colonne_3 += $cols[3];
        $_colonne_4 += $cols[4];
        $_colonne_5 += $cols[5];
        $_colonne_6 += $cols[6];
        $_colonne_7 += $cols[7];
        $_colonne_8 += $cols[8];
        $_colonne_9 += $cols[9];
        $_colonne_10 += $cols[10];
        $_colonne_11 += $cols[11];
        $_colonne_12 += $cols[12];
        $_colonne_13 += $cols[13];
        $_colonne_14 += $cols[14];
        $_colonne_15 += $cols[15];
        $_colonne_16 += $cols[16];
        $_colonne_17 += $cols[17];
        $_colonne_18 += $cols[18];
        $_colonne_19 += $cols[19];
        $_colonne_20 += $cols[20];



//----------------------matrice - conserve les valeurs lues dans les "colonnes"

        $_colonne_matrice_1[] = $cols[1];
        $_colonne_matrice_2[] = $cols[2];
        $_colonne_matrice_3[] = $cols[3];
        $_colonne_matrice_4[] = $cols[4];
        $_colonne_matrice_5[] = $cols[5];
        $_colonne_matrice_6[] = $cols[6];
        $_colonne_matrice_7[] = $cols[7];
        $_colonne_matrice_8[] = $cols[8];
        $_colonne_matrice_9[] = $cols[9];
        $_colonne_matrice_10[] = $cols[10];
        $_colonne_matrice_11[] = $cols[11];
        $_colonne_matrice_12[] = $cols[12];
        $_colonne_matrice_13[] = $cols[13];
        $_colonne_matrice_14[] = $cols[14];
        $_colonne_matrice_15[] = $cols[15];
        $_colonne_matrice_16[] = $cols[16];
        $_colonne_matrice_17[] = $cols[17];
        $_colonne_matrice_18[] = $cols[18];
        $_colonne_matrice_19[] = $cols[19];
        $_colonne_matrice_20[] = $cols[20];

    }

    $diviseurArithmetique = $row - 1;

//---------------------------------------------------médias

    $_moyenne_colonne_1 = $_colonne_1 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_2 = $_colonne_2 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_3 = $_colonne_3 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_4 = $_colonne_4 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_5 = $_colonne_5 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_6 = $_colonne_6 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_7 = $_colonne_7 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_8 = $_colonne_8 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_9 = $_colonne_9 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_10 = $_colonne_10 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_11 = $_colonne_11 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_12 = $_colonne_12 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_13 = $_colonne_13 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_14 = $_colonne_14 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_15 = $_colonne_15 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_16 = $_colonne_16 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_17 = $_colonne_17 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_18 = $_colonne_18 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_19 = $_colonne_19 / $diviseurArithmetique;
    $_moyenne_colonne_20 = $_colonne_20 / $diviseurArithmetique;



    $nEchantillons = $diviseurArithmetique - 1;


//-------------------------------Contrôle les indices et les moyennes des colonnes


    $m[] = '';
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_1;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_2;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_3;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_4;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_5;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_6;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_7;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_8;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_9;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_10;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_11;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_12;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_13;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_14;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_15;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_16;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_17;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_18;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_19;
    $m[] = $_colonne_matrice_20;


    $m0[] = '';
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_1;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_2;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_3;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_4;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_5;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_6;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_7;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_8;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_9;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_10;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_11;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_12;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_13;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_14;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_15;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_16;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_17;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_18;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_19;
    $m0[] = $_colonne_matrice_20;


    $m1[] = '';
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_1;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_2;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_3;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_4;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_5;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_6;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_7;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_8;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_9;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_10;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_11;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_12;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_13;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_14;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_15;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_16;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_17;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_18;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_19;
    $m1[] = $_moyenne_colonne_20;








    $m2[] = '';
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_1;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_2;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_3;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_4;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_5;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_6;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_7;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_8;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_9;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_10;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_11;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_12;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_13;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_14;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_15;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_16;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_17;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_18;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_19;
    $m2[] = $_moyenne_colonne_20;



//-----------------------------------------------Coefficient

echo ('<div class="container">');

    echo ('<div class="linha">');

        for ($t = 65; $t < 85; $t++)
        {
            echo ('<div class="header borda">&#'.$t.';</div>');
        }
    
    echo ('</div>');


    echo ('<div class="colStamps">');

        for ($t = 65; $t < 85; $t++)
        {
            echo ('<div class="colAb bordaRight">&#'.$t.';</div>');
        }

    echo ('</div>');


    for ($s = 1; $s < 21; $s++)
    {
        for ($f = 1; $f < 21; $f++)
        {
            echo ('<div class="col">');

            for ($ii = 0; $ii < $diviseurArithmetique; $ii++)
            {
                $sommeT += (($m[$s][$ii] - $m1[$s]) * ($m0[$f][$ii] - $m2[$f]) );

                $sommeQ += (($m[$s][$ii] - $m1[$s]) ** 2 );

                $sommeQQ += (($m0[$f][$ii] - $m2[$f]) ** 2 );
            }

            $sommeQ2 = sqrt($sommeQ * $sommeQQ);
            $d = $sommeT / $sommeQ2;

            if ($d == 1)
            {
                echo ('<span class="destaque">'.$d.'</span>');
            }
            else
            {
                echo (number_format($d,2,",","."));
            }

            $sommeT = 0;
            $sommeQ = 0;
            $sommeQQ = 0;
            $sommeQ2 = 0;
            echo ('</div>');
        }
    }

echo ('</div>');

?>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Here is the result]

I would like to have the results in different columns.
The objective of this code is to correlate user's preferences collected in the data.csv, where each column represents a user, and each user gives a score between 1 and 5 to differents products represented in rows.

Comment: Have you tried using a "regular" table instead? After all, it's tabular data

Comment: Have you tried <th> and <tr> elements? instead of only using divs?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/**
 * If I understand you correctly, the data.csv file looks like:
 *          ; User 1; User 2; User 3
 * Product A;      1;      1;      1
 * Product B;      2;      2;      2
 *
 * Then the easiest thing to do is convert it to an array that looks like:
 * $data[
 *     [
 *         'user' => 'User 1',
 *         'products' => [
 *             [
 *                 'product' => 'Product A',
 *                 'score' => 1
 *             ],
 *             [
 *                 'product' => 'Product B',
 *                 'score' => 2
 *             ]
 *         ]
 *     ],
 *     // Etc...
 * ];
 */
$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'r');
$firstRow = true;
$firstColumn = true; // Assuming first column/row is empty

$users = [];

while (($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, ';')) !== false) {
    // Built user list from columns in first row.
    if ($firstRow) {
        foreach ($line as $user) {
            // Skip first empty column.
            if ($firstColumn) {
                $firstColumn = false;
                continue;
            }

            $users[] = [
                'user' => $user,
                'products' => []
            ];
        }
        $firstRow = false;
        continue;
    }

    // Remove product from line.
    $product = array_shift($line);

    // Reset indexes.
    $line = array_values($line);

    foreach ($line as $userIndex => $userScore) {
        $user[$userIndex]['products'][] = [
            'product' => $product,
            'score' => $userScore
        ];
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- And then print the array (with table or div) -->
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;<!-- First empty (top left) --></th>
                <?php
                foreach ($users as $user) {
                    echo '<th>' . $user['user'] . '</th>';
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            // Grab list of products from first entry.
            $products = $users[0]['products'];
            
            // Loop through all products.
            foreach ($products as $index => $product) {
                // Grab product name (first column).
                echo '<tr><th>'.$product['product'].'</th>';

                // Loop through all users and grab score for selected product.
                foreach ($users as $user) {
                    echo '<td>' . $user['products'][$index]['score'] . '</td>';
                }
                
                // Close row.
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<?php

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm not printing the csv itself, I'm printing in a table format the correlations that I calculated in the code.